# nginx location zero or one trailing slash at the end of URL

Tags: regex, nginx, nginx-location

```
location ~ ^/random/?$ {
       try_files $uri $uri/ /api/random.php;
    }
```

I have this rule in my nginx config file and I want to be able to call this URL like `/random` or `/random/`

The problem is that this rule allows infinte trailing slashes at the end like /random///// for ex. will also work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nginx` uses a normalised URI when matching `location` directives, so multiple consecutive `/`s have already been reduce to a single `/` by the time your regular expression is tested.

You could reject multiple consecutive `/`s by testing the `$request_uri` variable, which contains the original URI together with query string (if any). For example:

```
if ($request_uri ~ //) { return 403; }
```